# Creating a JavaScript SOAP Client

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm creating a SOAP Client with JS, this is my first time with webServices and I must have several mistakes in my code.

The poit is, with my code, I cant take acces to the WebService, but I don't know how to access to the methods inside. So the webservice gives me the following response:

```
<h1>Version</h1>
<p>Hi there, this is an AXIS service!</p>
<i>Perhaps there will be a form for invoking the service here...</i>
```

Instead of the correct XML for the method I'm calling.

This is the code of my SOAP client:

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function run(){

        var objXMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        objXMLHttpRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyWS/services/Version?wdsl/", true);
        objXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        //alert(objXMLHttpRequest.readyState+"   "+ objXMLHttpRequest.status);
        if (objXMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && objXMLHttpRequest.status == 200) {
            result = objXMLHttpRequest.responseXML;
            alert(objXMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            alert(objXMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
          }
        }
        objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        var packet = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><getVersion xmlns="http://service.web.com.crunchify/"></getVersion></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

        objXMLHttpRequest.send(packet);
        // Add mentioned below code only if your application calls webservice synchronously. Otherwise use "onreadystatechange" process response.
        response = objXMLHttpRequest.responseXML;
        alert(objXMLHttpRequest.responseText+ "  "+ response);
    }
</script>

<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button  onclick="run()">Dale!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I think that te mistake should be in the  part, but, as I said, this is my first time and I don't know what I'm doing.

SOLVED

Comment: I read diagonally but try "POST" instead of "GET"? Most soap endpoints are post-only.

Comment: When try POST instead of GET I've got 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
   <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
   <detail>
    <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">WebServices-PC</ns2:hostname>
   </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Yes, in version 1.1 of SOAP you need to add a soapaction. This soapaction can be retrieved from the WSDL and has to be passed in as a HTTP header.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that? I know is a very dumb question, but I'm am very new with this

Comment: Search your wsdl for "getVersion" which is the root tag of your request. There is most likely an operation with that name (as it appears to be document literal wrapped) and near the binding of that operation is a tag with the soapaction, copy the value and put it in a HTTP header (using the same setRequestHeader) with the key "SOAPAction".

Comment: Something like that?

objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8", "SOAPAction=getVersion");

It stills give de ERROR 500

Comment: Leave the original `objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");` alone and simply add a new line saying `objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "mySoapAction");`

Comment: THANK YOU! You make my day! It's finally works. Thank you a lot! ^^

Answer (score 0):

the first problem could be on this line :

```
objXMLHttpRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyWS/services/Version?wdsl/", true);
```

this url 
http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyWS/services/Version?wsdl
gives you the list of the services you can call.

So you'll probably have something like that :

```
objXMLHttpRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyWS/services/myServiceMethod", true);
```

That's the first problem i think.
In a second time, you have to send your parameters but not the entire Soap envelope.

```
var packet = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><getVersion xmlns="http://service.web.com.crunchify/"></getVersion></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

objXMLHttpRequest.send(packet);
```

Like :

```
var parameters = "param1=15&param2=30"
objXMLHttpRequest.send(parameters);
```

And the method send should be out of 
objXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (){}

this function is a callback to examine the response.

Don't hesitate to look at this link :
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp

Hope this help

Comment: The thing is that the method has no parameters.

This is the wdsl of the WS: http://pastebin.com/3QejHfqz

I really don't know how I must do this :(

Answer (score 0):

You can check the comments for the evolution of the answer, but in short:

1) SOAP method calls are requires to use the HTTP method "POST", so the GET action was the first issue.

2) In SOAP 1.1 the SOAPAction header is required for the server to know which method you are trying to call. When using the "document literal wrapped" methodology this is not strictly necessary and a lot of SOAP 1.1 servers actually accept empty soap actions because they can find the method based on the root tag of the request hence providing some forward compatibility with SOAP 1.2.

However strict SOAP 1.1 servers will require the SOAPAction header to be sent along correctly:

```
objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "mySoapAction");
```

Where you can find the corresponding SOAPAction for the method you are trying to call in the original WSDL of the webservice.